# PHP & MySQL Including a Delete button on same page

Tags: php, mysql, function

First and foremost thank you for taking a look at my question. This is somewhat one of my first MySql/PHP projects and wondering if there was a way to condense these two pages I have created.

Basically I have a MySql database with some dummy filler info in. I have created a php page that displays the info:

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "testdelete"); //for local machine testing

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// select record from mysql 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM testdelete.test_mysql";
$result = $link->query($sql);




if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    include 'table_header.html';
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">".$row["id"]."</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">". $row["name"]."</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row["lastname"]."</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">". $row["email"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"test_delete_ac.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete row</a></td>";
         echo "</tr>";

     }

     include 'table_footer.html';
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}



// close connection
mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Based on the code sample, each row of data displays and there is a column for the delete button so I can delete a row when I want. However, the way it is set up now is it calls a secondary page "test_delete_ac.php" as shown below:

```
<?php

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "testdelete"); //for local machine testing

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// select record from mysql 
//$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM testdelete.test_mysql";
//$result = $link->query($sql);

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM testdelete.test_mysql WHERE id='$id'";
$result=$link->query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='delete.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}



// close connection
mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

One for usability I want to limit it from going to a secondary page, and having to click the "go back" link. And two can I create a function and call it from the link to delete the row and still show the form? Like the page reloads or something?

Thanks in advance for any redirection any of you may be able to offer.

-Kate

Comment: You can redirect from the delete script back to the first page.

Comment: You will not be able to use a PHP function that you can call from the link, if that is what you are asking. PHP is executed only on the server-side and provides no client-side functionality. You can accomplish this 1 of 2 ways. 1) use a PHP redirect at the end of the delete script or 2) use AJAX to call the delete page and then refresh the current page on success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just include the delete logic above your select statement.

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "testdelete"); //for local machine testing

// Check connection
if ($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Handle delete
if (isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    // get value of id that sent from address bar 
    $delete_id = (int) $_GET['delete_id'];

    // Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
    $sql="DELETE FROM testdelete.test_mysql WHERE id='$delete_id'";
    $result=$link->query($sql);

    // if successfully deleted
    if ($result){
        echo "Deleted Successfully";
        echo "<BR>";
    } else {
        echo "Delete ERROR";
    }
}

// select record from mysql 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM testdelete.test_mysql";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    include 'table_header.html';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">".$row["id"]."</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">". $row["name"]."</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row["lastname"]."</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">". $row["email"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"?delete_id={$row['id']}\">Delete row</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
     include 'table_footer.html';
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Be careful with this approach, though. Since it's just a link, and if it's public, a bot can crawl and delete everything.

Also, note that there are a few other changes. I changed the param from `id` to `delete_id`, just to avoid ambiguity. I updated the delete link. I'm checking that `$_GET['delete_id']` is set before running the delete query. And, I'm casting (int) on `$_GET['delete_id']` to make sure it's actually an integer.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, I will try out these methods then post to help someone else (or me) in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">
           <a href=\"test_delete_ac.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete row</a>
      </td>";
```

With this but replace current_page.php with the page where there is the list.:

```
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">
           <a href=\"current_page.php?parem=delete&amp;id={$row['id']}\">Delete row</a>
      </td>";
```

And put this at the top of your list page below the connection

```
  <?php
       if(isset($_GET['parem']) && $_GET['parem']=="delete"){
          $id=$_GET['id'];
         // Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
         $sql="DELETE FROM testdelete.test_mysql WHERE id='$id'";
         $result=$link->query($sql);

         // if successfully deleted
         if($result){
             //redirect of the list page it is recommended// so use location to redirect to the list page
         }else {
         echo "ERROR";
         }
    }
?>
 // put the list code over here.
```

And beside these try to avoid such things, its not a good practice. I would recommend to use class.

```
Replace <td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"> </td> with <td class='bgColor'> </td>
```