# Run Query from link in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, action, href

I have the following code:

```
foreach($resultsve as $line){
echo "<tr>";

$query_delete = "
DELETE FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`ID` = '".$line['ID']."'
";
$stmtdel = $conn->query($query_delete);

echo "<td><img src='./pictures/".$line['PICTURE']."'></td>";

echo "<td>" . $line['TITLE'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $line['YEAR'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $line['DURATION'] . " min" . "</td>";

echo "<td><a href='".$stmtdel = $conn->query($query_delete)."'>delete</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
```

Is there a way to run `query($query_delete)` from a href and stay on the same php file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL Including a Delete button on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317852/php-mysql-including-a-delete-button-on-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same page without refreshing you will have to do an AJAX call with javascript. Include the ID to delete and do the query on the separate page.

If you dont mind refreshing you can link to the same page with an delete action.

```
echo "<td><a href='yourpage.php?action=delete&id=".$line['id']."'>delete</a></td>";
```

then on top of this page

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete' && isset($_GET['id'])){
   $query_delete = "DELETE FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`ID` = '".$_GET['id']."'";
   $stmtdel = $conn->query($query_delete);
}
```